# Oracle SQL. Combine multiple tables to show data is failing

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to combine multiple tables to show data but it's failing.

Here is my code:

```
`SQL> SELECT CUST_ID, CUST_PHONE, MOVIE_COPY.COPY_NUM, RENTAL.COPY_NUM,BRANCH_NUM,RENTED_DATES,RETURN_DATES
  2  FROM RENTAL,CUSTOMER,MOVIE_COPY
  3  ON RENTAL.COPY_NUM = MOVIE_COPY.COPY_NUM
  4  WHERE CUST_ID=11004
  5  ORDER BY COPY_NUM DESC;
```

I'm getting "ERROR at line 3: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended"

Any help with the code?

`

Comment: You are mixing implicit and explicit join syntax. Stick to `join ... on` syntax rather than comma separated syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing the old legacy (comma) join syntax with the newer ANSI join syntax which is creating the error:

```
FROM  RENTAL, CUSTOMER, MOVIE_COPY
      ON   RENTAL.COPY_NUM = MOVIE_COPY.COPY_NUM
WHERE ...
```

is invalid.

```
FROM  RENTAL, CUSTOMER, MOVIE_COPY
WHERE RENTAL.COPY_NUM = MOVIE_COPY.COPY_NUM
AND   ...
```

(entirely using the legacy syntax) or

```
FROM  CUSTOMER, RENTAL INNER JOIN MOVIE_COPY
      ON RENTAL.COPY_NUM = MOVIE_COPY.COPY_NUM
WHERE ...
```

(using the newer ANSI join syntax) are valid.

If you convert to be using the newer syntax then your code should be something like:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b4a0d/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
  CUST_ID NUMBER,
  CUST_PHONE NUMBER
)
/
CREATE TABLE rental (
  copy_num NUMBER,
  branch_num NUMBER,
  rented_dates DATE,
  return_dates DATE
)
/
CREATE TABLE movie_copy (
  copy_num NUMBER
)
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT CUST_ID,
       CUST_PHONE,
       MOVIE_COPY.COPY_NUM,
       RENTAL.COPY_NUM,
       BRANCH_NUM,
       RENTED_DATES,
       RETURN_DATES
FROM   RENTAL
       CROSS JOIN CUSTOMER
       INNER JOIN MOVIE_COPY
       ON RENTAL.COPY_NUM = MOVIE_COPY.COPY_NUM
WHERE  CUST_ID=11004
ORDER BY MOVIE_COPY.COPY_NUM DESC
```

*Note: you do not have a join condition for `RENTAL` and `CUSTOMER` so it is using a `CROSS JOIN` - the newer syntax makes it clearer that this is missing and that you probably want to change this to an `INNER JOIN` and add the appropriate condition.*

Comment: I'm getting ERROR at line 3: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: @c0nfus3d I did not get that error - please check that you have copied it correctly.

Comment: OK I had put in a > instead of a , but now I get ERROR at line 12:
ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined with your code

Comment: @c0nfus3d That is because your `ORDER BY` clause could reference the `RENTAL` or the `MOVIE_COPY` table and you need to clarify which it is referencing as per my previous edit.

Comment: OK I tried your code again and entered it correctly using ORDER BYMOVIE_COPY.COPY_NUM DESC; but still ERROR at line 13:ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined. 13 WHERE CUST_ID=11004. Something is wrong with that line. Any ideas?

Comment: @c0nfus3d : Column `CUST_ID` is found in more than one table?

Comment: Yes in table CUSTOMER & table RENTAL. BRANCH_NUM is also found in table BRANCH if that helps.

Comment: @c0nfus3d Then you need to fix it by using the appropriate table names (or aliases) to prefix the column name - you didn't tell us what your table structure was in your table so we could only guess from your code.

Comment: Got it working. Thank you everyone for your help :) Thank you so much!

Comment: Of course it is possible to mix old legacy join syntax with new Ansi join syntax. It is probably not wise to do so. But there's no problem doing a "FROM CUSTOMER, RENTAL inner join MOVIE_COPY
  3  ON RENTAL.COPY_NUM = MOVIE_COPY.COPY_NUM". It's somewhat ideological to say that one join syntax is superior to the other. Having to work with legacy systems, I have to say, it's necessary to use and understand both!

Comment: I agree with @sers; specifically with the first part. It is not true that mixing legacy and standard join syntax is itself resulting in an error. It doesn't. Actually Oracle documents the specific rules that apply when the two are mixed in the same query. This doesn't change the fact that mixing them in the same query is borderline insane, but as an explanation for why a query results in an error, that is not it.

Comment: @mathguy The problem (among others) was that the OP was mixing both syntax in one join: `FROM RENTAL,CUSTOMER,MOVIE_COPY ON RENTAL.COPY_NUM = MOVIE_COPY.COPY_NUM` when they either needed to change the `ON` clause to part of the `WHERE` clause (and completely use the old syntax) or use the ANSI join and the `ON` clause - you cannot use a comma join and an `ON` clause together for a single join.

Comment: @sers I never said it was not possible - I said it wasn't possible to mix the syntax in a single join. `FROM CUSTOMER,RENTAL,MOVIE_COPY ON RENTAL.COPY_NUM = MOVIE_COPY.COPY_NUM` is invalid but `FROM CUSTOMER,RENTAL INNER JOIN MOVIE_COPY ON RENTAL.COPY_NUM = MOVIE_COPY.COPY_NUM` and `FROM RENTAL,CUSTOMER,MOVIE_COPY WHERE RENTAL.COPY_NUM = MOVIE_COPY.COPY_NUM` are both valid.

Comment: Oh - OK, my bad, I didn't read the OP's query closely. The point you are making (I would have worded it differently) is that the OP's query does NOT use EITHER legacy OR ANSI syntax, because he does not use the JOIN keyword but he does have an ON condition. That is neither legacy nor ANSI syntax - it is not "mixing" the two, it is mixing a little bit of each into the same join. But other than the wording, I see what you are saying, and I agree.

Answer (score 0):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit, proper `JOIN` syntax.

Your query should look something like this:

```
SELECT C.CUST_ID, C.CUST_PHONE, MC.COPY_NUM,
       R.COPY_NUM, R.BRANCH_NUM, R.RENTED_DATES, R.RETURN_DATES
FROM RENTAL R JOIN
     CUSTOMER C
     ON R.CUST_ID = C.CUST_ID JOIN
     MOVIE_COPY MC
     ON R.COPY_NUM = MC.COPY_NUM
WHERE C.CUST_ID = 11004
ORDER BY R.COPY_NUM DESC;
```

Note that I've qualified the column names.  I may not have the tables correct.  You should always use qualified column names when your query has more than one table reference.

Comment: I'm getting ERROR at line 5: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended with your code

Comment: @c0nfus3d . . . I don't see anything obviously wrong that would cause that problem.

Comment: SQL> SELECT CUSTOMER.CUST_ID, CUSTOMER.CUST_PHONE, MOVIE_COPY.COPY_NUM,RENTAL.COPY_NUM, MOVIE_COPY.MOVIE_TITLE, MOVIE_COPY.BRANCH_NUM, RENTAL.RENTED_DATES, RENTAL.RETURN_DATES
2 FROM RENTAL R JOIN
3 CUSTOMER C
4 ON RENTAL.CUST_ID = CUSTOMER.CUST_ID JOIN
5 MOVIE_COPY MC
6 ON RENTAL.COPY_NUM = MOVIE_COPY.COPY_NUM
7 WHERE C.CUST_ID = 11004
8 ORDER BY MOVIE_COPY.COPY_NUM DESC;
ON RENTAL.CUST_ID = CUSTOMER.CUST_ID JOIN
*
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00904: "CUSTOMER"."CUST_ID": invalid identifier

Comment: @c0nfus3d . . . That is not the query in this answer.

Comment: Hmm sorry messed up, ran your code again and got ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00904: "R"."BRANCH_NUM": invalid identifier. BTW BRANCH_NUM is in table BRANCH. Do I need to join that to?

Comment: @c0nfus3d . . . Remove it from the query.  It was in your original query, which didn't reference `BRANCH`.

Comment: OK got it working. thank you so much for your effort in helping me :)

Comment: Your statement of "never use commas in from clause" is not technical but ideological.

Comment: I agree with @sers (see comment above this one). Moreover, "Never use commas" is flat-out incorrect. There are (a small number of) instances where ANSI join syntax is actually prohibited (by Oracle's unhealthy rules). One of those is materialized views with refresh on commit. They do allow joins, but only if the joins use the old, Oracle proprietary syntax.